# Getting previous order id in an Observer

Tags: php, magento, observer-pattern

I'm writing an observer for the *checkout_submit_all_after* event and it works fine. When you edit an order, for example the #1001, magento creates a new one with #1001-1 and cancel the previous order.

The admin panel tells me that #1001-1 is linked to the #1001, so how can I know if the current order is actually a modified version?

Is there some function/variable for this purpose?

thanks

Comment: try to dump your order object and look inside print_r($order)

Comment: it doesn't work, the page freeze or return a blank output. The docs for Mage_Sales_Model_Order, the class of order it's not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!

```
  $current_id = $order->getRealOrderId(); // #1001-2
  $previous_id = $order->getRelationParentRealId(); // #1001-1
  $older_id = $order->getOriginalIncrementId(); // #1001
```